# how to send a file to the minicom through the linux terminal?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, putty, pipeline

I am using a Raspberry Pi on Raspbian with minicom installed on it, and am connecting it through serial(using a transceiver) to Putty installed on Windows.I cannot use other protocols, due to the nature of the project.

I used a script to create a file every second, with the measurements of some sensors, and want to send the files automatically to my laptop. My current way of sending files automatically to Putty is by writing a shell script on Raspberry Pi with this code inside a for loop which adds 1 to the variable "i" each time:

```
cat (file$i.txt) | minicom -b 19200 -o -D /dev/ttyAMA0
```

However, this way I can only send the contents of each file, rather than files separately. Is there a similar way to send the files themselves from the terminal or a script, other than by opening minicom manually and using the "send file" function?

Answer (score 0):

The serial console is a character device, meaning that it sends and received a stream of bytes, not files.
In order to send whole files, you need a protocol above the layer 1 that the serial port provides.

You could implement it on your own, or check out [Kermit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kermit_%28protocol%29).

There's also a pypi package named [serialXfer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/serialXfer), check it out.

Comment: Isn't minicom doing, what Kermit does?